# Azure Devops Dry Run Import failed and I am unable to remove organization after fixing issues

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

I ran a migration to import my on premise Azure Devops Server to Azure Devops Service account.  However, the dry run import failed.  In that process it created a new organization **[OrganizationName]-dryrun**.  When I click on that organization I get a **"Import Failed"** screen, and I can't remove the organization.  I was able to correct the issues, thanks to the email that I received upon failure.  But now I can't re-attempt the import because the organization exists.

Anyone know of a way to get rid of this failed organization so I can re-attempt the import?

Comment: Did you tried below solution? How did it go?

Answer (score 1):

Organization can be deleted in the organization setting page.
Click on **Organization Setting** at the left bottom corner.

Go to **Overview** and choose **Delete** at the end of the page.
[image]

Click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/delete-your-organization?view=azure-devops) for details